# SmtpClient SendMailAsync with bulk emails successfully sends about 1200, rest of them fail. Any pointers?

Tags: c#, smtpclient

Here is the code. I have tried SendAsync too but ran into the same. I need to broadcast email messages to the subscribers.

```
var emails = Enumerable.Repeat("<my email address>", 1300);
        string mMailServer = "<smtp server>";

        int counter = 0;
        foreach (var item in emails)
        {
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(mMailServer);
            MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("<from address>", item, "bulk test from blast", "test")
            {
                IsBodyHtml = true
            };

            var t = client.SendMailAsync(mm);
            t.ContinueWith(async (inp) =>
            {

                if (inp.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
                {
                }
                if (inp.IsFaulted)
                {
                    var ex = $"{ inp.Exception.Message} Inner Exception: { inp.Exception.InnerException?.Message }";
                    await Util.WriteToFileAsync(@"d:\errorMessages\", counter.ToString(), inp.Exception.Message);
                }
            });
            counter++;
        }
```

Comment: Wrap the SmtpClient in a Using statement so the object gets disposed when you leave the using.  Put inside the foreach loop.

Comment: Without information how this fails there is not much to work with... (Note that you should find provider that does not care about sending spam/bulk mails - there is a good chance that regular one will throttle bulk sends)

Comment: The exception message I am getting is "One or more errors occurred. (Syntax error, command unrecognized. The server response was: )". That is all.

Comment: It is my company's SMTP server. Could you let me know where to look for throttle setting.

Comment: adding using actually hurt (I had tried that earlier), with it no emails are getting sent.